# how to solve this overlapping dropdown menu in bootstrap theme

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overlapping

ive downloaded a bootstrap theme and tweak it a little. I added a caret and a dropdown in the top of my div but the menu dropdown was being covered by my sidebar. i want to make it in front of it, Here is the image:

[image]

Here is the code in my dropdown:

```
.custom-drop {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 105px;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.frontview {
  z-index: 5000;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a><span class="caret"></span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu custom-drop">
  <li class="frontview"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li class="frontview"><a href="#">Sign-out</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its simple, your sidebar has a higher `z-index`, try setting the `z-index` to something like 10000 on the dropdowns

Comment: @ImmortalDude i already declared z-index: 5000;

Comment: that's why i said to try increasing the `z-index` to some thing like 10000, also check for `overflow:hidden` that could be cropping your navigation dropdown

Comment: @ImmortalDude i tried z-index of 10000 but still overlap?

Comment: then check for overflows, it might not be a overlap but rather a `overflow:hidden`

Comment: @ImmortalDude hello sir, if i remove my overflow, my navigation sidebar will be gone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135845/discussion-between-immortal-dude-and-jc-john).

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Immortal Dude suggestion. If it still doesn't work, you can also try and set your sidebar z-index to -1.

Comment: appreciate your support